# Which of the following is not the correct quadratic equation?

Tags: reference-request, systems-of-equations, roots

If $3/2$ and $4$ are the two roots of a quadratic equation, then which one of the following is not the correct quadratic equation?

(A) $2x^2-11x+6=0$,

(B) $6x^2-33x+18=0$,

(C) $-10x^2-55x-30=0$,

(D) $4x^2-41x+24=0$.

I tried using the analogy $(x-3/2)(x-4)$ but it came to be of no use. My textbook tells me to interpret this as $k(x-3/2)(x-4)$. The equation comes out to have a constant ($c$ term) $+12$. However the options tell a different story altogether. A slight advice about the same will be most welcome.

Comment: You can try middle term splitting

Comment: $\frac{3}{2}$ and $4$ are not the roots of any of these equations.

Comment: So is the question wrong? Do you feel anything what the instructor wanted to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textbook is suggesting a uselessly complicated method.

The sum of the roots is $11/2$ and their product is $6$. Dividing by the leading coefficient should make the equation in the form
$$
x^2-\dfrac{11}{2}x+6=0
$$
and the form of this equation is unique. Now we have

(A) $x^2-\dfrac{11}{2}x+3=0$ (divide by $2$)

(B) $x^2-\dfrac{11}{2}x+3=0$ (divide by $6$)

(C) $x^2-\dfrac{11}{2}x+3=0$ (divide by $-10$)

(D) $x^2-\dfrac{41}{4}x+6=0$ (divide by $4$)

So the answer is that *none* of the proposed equations has roots $3/2$ and $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The first three equations are identical, to a constant factor. D) is different.

Anyway,

$$2\left(x-\dfrac32\right)(x-4)=2x^2-11x+12$$

shows that *the question* is wrong.

---

Alternatively, you can plug $4$ or $\dfrac32$ in the equations and see that you don't get $0$.